# Why menu's items are not showing in bottom navigation bar in android studio?

Tags: android

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#C8C3C3"
    android:id="@+id/layout">
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/round_shape"
        android:layout_margin="30dp"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        app:menu="@menu/item_menu"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/black"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here I am adding bottom nav bar where menu's item will be shown. But items are not showing in the nav bar.

**item_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:title="Home"
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_shopping"/>
    <item android:title="Cart"
        android:id="@+id/cart"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_shopping"/>
    <item android:title="Notification"
        android:id="@+id/notification"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_shopping"/>
    <item android:title="Profile"
        android:id="@+id/profile"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_shopping"/>
</menu>
```

Here is the code of item's menu.

Comment: Can you show us your gradle file ? Where all dependencies are listed

Comment: implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie:4.2.2"implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0' @casper